# Customized callout bubble MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

What I am wanting to do is to create a custom callout bubble in MKMapView, just as it is explained in http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/, but it seems that there are some bugs in that otherwise nicely done application. For example, when you leave the custom callout bubble open, and scroll away, then at some point the map scrolls back to the open callout. Also zooming sometimes triggers this bug. Has anyone been able to solve those problems? Sorry for creating a new question (as there are a couple addressing custom callout bubble), but I did not have enough rep points to comment an answer.

Comment: Is there code in that example that should close the callout but doesn't?  Maybe you could provide a relevant excerpt here and we can try to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think any code is ever supposed to close it (when mimicking apple behaviour), unless they open it again when it becomes visible, maybe you meant that?

Comment: This is definitely a bug.  I've been using this code for a while now, but never ran across this case.  Basically if you scroll the callout bubble out of view and then tap the map, it thinks you are tapping the annotation and that the callout is NOT displayed, so it's re-adjusting the screen so the callout will be displayed.  Gotta work on this for a while.  Thanks for finding the bug.

Answer (score -1):

The fix for this is in CalloutMapAnnotationView: didMoveToSuperview,
   if we're de-selecting the annotation, then do not call adjustMapRegionIfNeeded.

So the way I fixed it is in my mapViewController: didDeselectAnnotationView, I assign a non-zero tag value to the BasicMapAnnotationView right before I removeAnnotation from the mapView.  I chose 159.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

// distinguish between the map deselecting this and the user tapping on the callout.
//   in the former case, we want to deselect as normal; latter case, show coupon detail.

if ( [view isKindOfClass:[BasicMapAnnotationView class]] ) {
    if ( ((BasicMapAnnotationView *)view).calloutMapAnnotation ) {
        if ( !((BasicMapAnnotationView *)view).preventSelectionChange) {
            ((BasicMapAnnotationView *)view).tag = 159;  // prevent adjusting map - see CalloutMapAnnotationView
            [mapView removeAnnotation: ((BasicMapAnnotationView *)view).calloutMapAnnotation];
            // if we're deselecting the currently selected one, null out self.selectedAnnotationView
            // Otherwise, the map view is deselecting this one in order to select another one
            // and the timing is such that this nulling happens first, and the newly set AV would have no value for this.
            if ( (BasicMapAnnotationView *)view == self.selectedAnnotationView ) {
                self.selectedAnnotationView=nil;
            }
            ((BasicMapAnnotationView *)view).calloutMapAnnotation = nil;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then, in CalloutMapAnnotationView, I check for this value, and if found, I don't adjust the map.

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
if ( self.parentAnnotationView ) {
    if ( self.parentAnnotationView.superview ) {   
        // null superview means it's been removed from map, and adjustMap gets wrong parentOrigin based on null superview,
        // and recenters the map somewhere in Antarctica.  The Ross Ice Shelf has no coupons except for frozen penguin eggs.

        if ( self.parentAnnotationView.tag != 159 ) {// Don't adjust map region on deselect. 
                                                     //159 hardcoded in MapViewController:didDeselectAnnotationView
            [self adjustMapRegionIfNeeded];
        }
        [self animateIn];
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: BasicMapAnnotationView does not have property calloutMapAnnotation, and adding it does not do much good yet, since no value is ever assigned to it (apart from nil, though that cannot be reached at the moment). Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Could you possibly provide the whole code? Unless I completely missed something, in neither part 1 nor part 2 is calloutMapAnnotation given any sensible value. I tried the additions you gave as such, but they did not work, I guess calloutMapAnnotation property is to blame.